# org.springframework.messaging.converter.MessageConversionException: No converter found from actual payload type 'byte[]' to expected payload

Tags: java, spring, spring-jms

I have a spring boot application , using @EnableJMS in configuration class and @JMSListener in listener class

In configuration class i have created a bean for connection Factory and a bean for message converter

something like this:

```
@Bean // Serialize message content to json using TextMessage
  public MessageConverter jacksonJmsMessageConverter() {
    MappingJackson2MessageConverter converter = new MappingJackson2MessageConverter();
    converter.setTargetType(MessageType.TEXT);
    converter.setTypeIdPropertyName("_type");
    return converter;
  }
```

My listener class looks like this:

```
@Component
public class Receiver {

  @JmsListener(destination = "abcqueue", containerFactory = "myFactory")
  public void receiveMessage(Message<MyModel> mymodel) {
    System.out.println("Received <");
  }

}
```

Error message:

```
; nested exception is org.springframework.messaging.converter.MessageConversionException: No converter found from actual payload type 'byte[]' to expected payload type 'com.model.MyModel', failedMessage=org.springframework.jms.listener.adapter.AbstractAdaptableMessageListener$MessagingMessageConverterAdapter$LazyResolutionMessage@3e8728
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.adapter.MessagingMessageListenerAdapter.invokeHandler(MessagingMessageListenerAdapter.java:118) ~[spring-jms-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.adapter.MessagingMessageListenerAdapter.onMessage(MessagingMessageListenerAdapter.java:77) ~[spring-jms-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.doInvokeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:736) ~[spring-jms-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.invokeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:696) [spring-jms-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.doExecuteListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:674) [spring-jms-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractPollingMessageListenerContainer.doReceiveAndExecute(AbstractPollingMessageListenerContainer.java:318) [spring-jms-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractPollingMessageListenerContainer.receiveAndExecute(AbstractPollingMessageListenerContainer.java:257) [spring-jms-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageListenerInvoker.invokeListener(DefaultMessageListenerContainer.java:1189) [spring-jms-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageListenerInvoker.executeOngoingLoop(DefaultMessageListenerContainer.java:1179) [spring-jms-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageListenerInvoker.run(DefaultMessageListenerContainer.java:1076) [spring-jms-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [?:1.8.0_251]
Caused by: org.springframework.messaging.converter.MessageConversionException: No converter found from actual payload type 'byte[]' to expected payload type MyModel'
    at org.springframework.messaging.handler.annotation.support.MessageMethodArgumentResolver.convertPayload(MessageMethodArgumentResolver.java:135) ~[spring-messaging-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.messaging.handler.annotation.support.MessageMethodArgumentResolver.resolveArgument(MessageMethodArgumentResolver.java:93) ~[spring-messaging-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.messaging.handler.invocation.HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.resolveArgument(HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.java:117) ~[spring-messaging-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.messaging.handler.invocation.InvocableHandlerMethod.getMethodArgumentValues(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:148) ~[spring-messaging-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.messaging.handler.invocation.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:116) ~[spring-messaging-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.adapter.MessagingMessageListenerAdapter.invokeHandler(MessagingMessageListenerAdapter.java:114) ~[spring-jms-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
```

Comment: Can you share the full stack trace?

Comment: Updated the full error stack

Answer (score 0):

I have similar problem, when I have `LocalDateTime` in my model, but get `ZonedDateTime` value (2023-01-10T12:00:28.591+0000).

Then I changed `LocalDateTime` to `ZonedDateTime` in model class and the problem has gone.